Part of Python Script doesnt run when called with JAVA
Im calling this python script via the java constructor but when the output is printed the last line that's printed is print("===> Build the model and recognizer objects.  This will take a few minutes."). The python script on itself works seamlessly. I have put a print("1") for reference in the python script to mark the problematic line.
ccPage.java
`ccPage() throws IOException {
setLayout(null);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setSize(800, 480);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocation(350, 200);

    Path pythonScriptPath = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().resolve(Paths.get("src/software/pythonFiles/audioProcess.py"));

    // Create a new Python interpreter
    try(Interpreter py = new SubInterpreter()){
        // Execute the Python script
        py.runScript(pythonScriptPath.toString());

        // Get the variable `mystring` from the Python script
        String mystring = py.getValue("mystring").toString();

        // Create a JLabel to display the value of `mystring`
        mystringLabel = new JLabel(mystring);
        mystringLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 20);
        add(mystringLabel);

        // Continuously fetch the updated value of `mystring` from the Python script
        while (true) {
            // Get the updated value of `mystring` from the Python script
            mystring = py.getValue("mystring").toString();

            // Update the JLabel to display the updated value of `mystring`
            mystringLabel.setText(mystring);

            // Sleep for 1 second
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (JepException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}`

audioProcess.py
import os
import queue

from pathlib import Path
import sounddevice as sd
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer
import sys
import json

import subprocess                  #Test line!
pipe = subprocess.PIPE             #Test line!

'''This script processes audio input from the microphone and displays the transcribed text.'''

# list all audio devices known to your system
print("Display input/output devices")
print(sd.query_devices())

# get the samplerate - this is needed by the Kaldi recognizer
device_info = sd.query_devices(sd.default.device[0], 'input')
samplerate = int(device_info['default_samplerate'])

# display the default input device
print("===> Initial Default Device Number:{} Description: {}".format(sd.default.device[0], device_info))

# setup queue and callback function
q = queue.Queue()

myString = ""

def recordCallback(indata, frames, time, status):
    if status:
        print(status, file=sys.stderr)
    q.put(bytes(indata))


# build the model and recognizer objects.
print("===> Build the model and recognizer objects.  This will take a few minutes.")
model_file: Path = Path(os.path.abspath("vosk-model-small-en-us-0.15"))
print("1")
model = Model(model_file.as_posix())
recognizer = KaldiRecognizer(model, samplerate)

print("===> Begin recording. Press Ctrl+C to stop the recording ")
try:
    with sd.RawInputStream(dtype='int16',
                           channels=1,
                           callback=recordCallback,
                           blocksize=100,
                           samplerate=samplerate,
                           extra_settings=pipe
                           ):
        # made changes that update the variable to be printed...
        while True:
            data = q.get()
            if recognizer.AcceptWaveform(data):
                recognizerResult = recognizer.Result()
                # convert the recognizerResult string into a dictionary
                resultDict = json.loads(recognizerResult)
                if not resultDict.get("text", "") == "":
                    print(recognizerResult)
                    myString = recognizerResult
                else:
                    print("no input sound")
                    myString = ""

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('===> Finished Recording')
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))

Assuming that it was a path access issue (which I think it is). I tried changing relative path of the model to using absolute path using OS module in python. I was expecting that the model gets found. But it doesnt throw any errors or such. It just stops.

This while (true) { seems problematic on two fronts.  1) Swing is not thread safe and is single threaded, so either you're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread or violating the thread model, in either case it's bad; 2) There's no flow control, no wait to actually exit the loop without force terminating JVM, which may leave resources dangling (like the python script running). My first recommendation would be to get rid of the UI and test the script as a stand alone concept, this will allow you to determine if the issue with python, the script or the intergration.

My second recommendation would be to then make use of SwingWorker to execute the script and make use of it's publish/process functionality to update the UI

Well to stop the python script, we need to press Ctrl+C anyways. Is there a workaround I'm overseeing?

First, I don't use python, but, I might look at the Interpreter capacity, see if it has a means to terminate the script (by sending a ctrl+c) or, update the script to have a exit value which can be set by the caller (again, I don't know if the Interpreter has a setValue method, these are just some ideas)

Yeah but I think that's the problem for later but the missing execution is the main problem I'm facing right now.

As I said - remove the UI from the equation - make a simple CLI app which just executes the script, see if that works.  If not, may consider investigating if the Interpreter has any thread I/O requirements (ie needing to read/write to/from the interpreter from different threads) - if this is working as you expect it to, then the likely issue is you've blocked the Event Dispatching Thread, which would mean you need to make use of a SwingWorker to resolve

Thank you for the detailed response. I'll try it out and let you know.
